# How to change the icon size of a color picker in JavaFX?

Tags: javafx

How to change the icon size of a color picker in javaFX. I'm having a problem, I can not increase the icon size of a color picker in JavaFX, does anyone know how to change the size of the button icon?

icon its small :(

[image: icon its small :(]

Comment: How did you generate that image, can you supply a [mcve] for that?  It looks like a shot from SceneBuilder, if so, perhaps include the generated FXML in your question.

Comment: Read about http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#colorpicker

Comment: How to change the default icon? I need to change the default icon,His size

Answer (score 4):

Setting the CSS attributes `-fx-color-rect-width` and `-fx-color-rect-width` will change size of the rectangle displayed.  Setting `fx-font-size` will change the size of the arrow.

[image: pickme]

Note that some of these attributes are not documented in the [official JavaFX CSS reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#colorpicker), so I guess future JavaFX iterations could change them without notice.  Still, at this stage, I think that is probably unlikely and the attributes are pretty safe to use.  To determine the undocumented CSS attributes, I looked at the source code for the ColorPickerSkin.

*pickme.css*

```
.large-rect-picker {
    -fx-color-rect-width: 60px;
    -fx-color-rect-height: 60px;
    -fx-color-label-visible: false;
    -fx-min-width: 150px;
    -fx-min-height: 100px;
    -fx-pref-width: 150px;
    -fx-pref-height: 100px;
}

.large-rect-picker > .arrow-button {
    -fx-font-size: 30px;
}
```

*PickMe.java*

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class PickMe extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
        colorPicker.getStyleClass().add("large-rect-picker");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(new Group(colorPicker)));
        stage.getScene().getStylesheets().add(
                PickMe.class.getResource(
                        "pickme.css"
                ).toExternalForm()
        );
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

---

*Aside info on asking questions*

It is difficult to know exactly what you want as you aren't really explicit in the question.  For instance what do you mean by icon? The rectangle or the down arrow or both?  What about the display that is popped up when you click on that arrow, should that change at all or stay the same?  For future questions, I recommend you be more specific about what you are trying to achieve and how it differs from what you have.  Showing code which produces what you have might also help others solve your issue.  Hopefully the info above is enough for you to modify it to accomplish what you wish.

Answer (score 0):

You can access and customize color picker by using css:

**ColorPicker**

*Style class: color-picker*

**Substructure**

- color display node — Label
- arrow-button — StackPane
- arrow — StackPane

The ColorPicker control has all the properties and pseudo‑classes of [ComboBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#comboboxbase)

**Example**

```
.color-picker .label {
     -fx-background-color: red; 
     -fx-text-fill: null;
     -fx-graphic: url("1487868456_Other_Antivirus_Software.png");//This is icon of Color picker label


}
```

**Result:**
[image: Customise color picker]

As far as I know you cant use -fx-width/-fx-height at all and you cant use percentage values for it. The width and height of elements are read-only. You can set -fx-pref-width, -fx-pref-height, -fx-max-width, -fx-min-width, -fx-max-height, -fx-min-height ,-fx-border-width and -fx-border-height to adjust the size of Java FX elements.

```
.picker-color {
    -fx-border-color:white ;  
    -fx-border-width:40;


}
```

[image: PickerColor]

Comment: How to change the default icon? I need to change the default icon,His size.

Comment: What i know is the ColorPicker control has all the properties and pseudo-classes of ComboBoxBase.Read https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#colorpicker.This is my limit about color picker.